# How to pass more than One Variable Args at ObjC method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2, variadic-functions

I need to receive more than one variable Args in my method. But I don't know how to do so.

For example:

```
(void)insertInTableOnAttributes:(id)fieldsNames, ... Values:(id)fieldsValues, ...;
```

sadly it appears a compiler error after the first `(...)` saying:

```
Expected ':' after method Prototype".
```

And in the implementation says:

```
Expected Method Body" in the same position (just after the first ...)
```

PD: I'm using Xcode 4.2.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that. How would the generated code possibly know where one argument list ends and the next begins? Try to think of the C equivalent

```
void insertInTableOnAtributes(id fieldNames, ..., id fieldValues, ...);
```

The compiler will reject that for the same reason.

You have two reasonable options. The first is to provide a method that takes `NSArray`s instead.

```
- (void)insertInTableOnAttributes:(NSArray *)fieldNames values:(NSArray *)fieldValues;
```

The second is to use one varargs with a name-value pair, similar to `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]`

```
- (void)insertInTableOnAttributes:(id)fieldName, ...;
```

This one would be used like

```
[obj insertInTableOnAttributes:@"firstName", @"firstValue", @"secondName", @"secondValue", nil];
```

---

The C analogy is actually quite accurate. An Obj-C method is basically syntactic sugar on top of a C method, so

```
- (void)foo:(int)x bar:(NSString *)y;
```

is backed by a C method that looks like

```
void foobar(id self, SEL _cmd, int x, NSString *y);
```

except it doesn't actually have a real name. This C function is called the `IMP` of the method, and you can retrieve it using obj-c runtime methods.

In your case of having arguments after a varargs, your

```
- (void)someMethodWithArgs:(id)anArg, ... andMore:(id)somethingElse;
```

would be backed by an `IMP` that looks like

```
void someMethodWithArgsAndMore(id anArg, ..., id somethingElse);
```

and since you cannot have any arguments after a varargs, this simply won't work.

Comment: The C analogy is not right, because the compiler could potentially tell where one list ends and the regular arguments begin by the placement of the named argument.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, it's actually quite literally correct. Obj-C methods are basically syntactic sugar on top of C methods. I'll update my post to explain.

Comment: Well, I assumed the space after the last item (being nil) would solve this. but I didn't saw the "C" way.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)insertInTableOnAttributes:(NSArray *)fieldsNames values:(NSArray *)fieldsValues;
```

// Use

```
[self insertInTableOnAttributes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name", nil] values:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"value", nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a Plan B, in case I couldn't find the answer.